# Should I revert edits that are helpful but shouldn't have been made?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-answer, rollbacks

Let's assume that a user made an edit to a post that was very helpful indeed, but should not have been made in accordance to [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

This is the [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66000992) that made me ask this question.

As it happens, the edit was helpful to the post, yet it was an improper use of an edit. In this case, should I revert the edit or let it stay there?

Comment: You link to an answer, but the quote you have included is from the portion of that FAQ page which is under the heading "Editing Code in **Questions**". Did you intend to be asking about an edit to a question or would the text in that FAQ under the heading "Editing Code in **Answers**" be more applicable to the situation about which you're asking?

Comment: You are referring to ***Don't*** on question, not on answers. Editing code in question is definitively a no-go, because it prevents from closing a question as *not reproducible due to typo*, now as far as answers are concerned this is a totally different kettle of fish

Comment: Then, definitely, no. Edits on answers, if they do fix an issue in the cod are Do's: *The code was using `stopPropragation()` instead of `stopPropagation()` so that was fixed*. It is in the FAQ you did link in a previous version of your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code > *Unlike questions, making an answer work is a good thing and should be encouraged with a few guidelines to follow.*

Comment: It depends on the edit itself. Can you link the post to which the edit was made? I would mostly say yes, as the goal of editing is to make the post better. But again, it heavily depends.

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated it's in the question history, it was originally included

Comment: @Spectric - this was an auto comment upon casting a close vote. Regardless, I think it actually answers the question if you take a look at the section about editing code in answers (β.εηοιτ.βε pointed that out above): "Fix syntax errors and typos". I think all responses here agree the original edit was a good one and followed the guidelines, we can just put up a signpost *for others* (I do not doubt you know how to make edits) here by closing in favor of the dupe target.

Comment: In general, I don't think Meta questions about specific Main questions should be closed as dupes of generic targets, as was done in this case. I think specific answers could be provided here that are targeted at the question the OP is asking about. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: If it was helpful, then by definition it should have been made

Comment: @cigien - well, the question is effectively answered by the FAQ, isn't it? And we seem to agree that the edit was good and not "shouldn't have been made" (and there is Dharman's answer), so is there a point for further discussion? Unless your point of view on the subject matter differs, of course.

Comment: @OlegValter It's not for me to say whether users can or can't provide additional viewpoints. I'm certainly not comfortable asserting that all possible viewpoints have been already been put forward. Besides, if one answer is acceptable I don't see why more answers couldn't be provided as well, regardless of whether I agree with the current sole answer.

Comment: @cigien I always thought that dupe closure is meant to ["help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). The target has an explanation of why the edit was proper, we also have a good answer here. Unless anyone wants to change the definition of a good code edit (which warrants a separate proposal), I see no point in keeping it open *indefinitely* and a clear benefit of a link to an important FAQ item. Anyway, to avoid bloating the discussion, let's let just let the voting system do its work.

Answer (score 12):

Why would you revert that?

If it was a positive edit that improved the post then what is the point in reverting it? The goal is to have clear on-topic questions that can be answered, and clear correct answers. If an edit is substantial to either question or answer but makes it better while keeping the original intent of the author then there is no reason to revert it.

If the edit changes the code then you can (if you are an expert in that field) evaluate the edit to make sure that the solution the original author wanted to present was kept and that the new code is still correct.

Don’t be afraid to make edits, but please respect the author. The author can always roll back the edit if they don’t like the improvement.

—-

When it comes to that particular answer, you should have made that edit instead of posting a comment. You chose to post a comment instead so another user stepped in and made the necessary edit. Why did you roll it back if you thought it was necessary to fix the answer?

Comment: @Spectric It is still possible for you to roll it back to the revision 3. Then you can even delete your comment

Comment: I think that edit was a good one. For answers, it is fine to change code because at the end of the day we want correct answers with correct code. I've had people edit code in my answers to make them better, which I fully appreciate.

Comment: I notice that you answered the question, and then voted to close it as a duplicate. Did you change your mind about the question needing an answer, or that it's actually a duplicate?

Comment: @cigien Not sure what you are asking. I answered and then I saw that the other answer is even better so I voted for it.

Comment: That's all I'm asking, i.e. did you change your mind after answering? Thanks for clarifying. I would have assumed that was the course of events originally, except that IIRC the duplicate suggestion was made before you posted your answer. Perhaps you just didn't notice the duplicate suggestion at the time, which is perfectly fine.